# Dynamic Link using AMPscript and Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am looking to make a dynamic link (updates automatically) to use across email studio so i can mass update a link across many emails. For example, i have LinkA in 20 different emails and I want to change that link all at once.

I figured i can create a DE and have a link associated with a linkID or something and use AMPscript to do a lookup and use that in a hyperlink. Is this the best solution?

So something like this:

DE is LinkDE

Link id | Link | Description

01 | [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) | linkdescription

`%%=Lookup('LinkDE','link','linkid',01)=%%`

Comment: You almost got it right, you just need to put the last parameter in the function in apostrophes: `%%=Lookup('LinkDE','link','linkid','01')=%%` and make sure your DE columns match what you write inside the function, eg. 'Link id' vs. 'linkid'

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Does the DE have to be sendable?

Comment: Nope, in fact it shouldn't be, you don't have any subscriber data in there

Comment: Not sure where i am going wrong. When i put %%=Lookup('LinkDE','link','linkid',01)=%% in a code snippet on an email and go to preview and test, nothing comes up...

Comment: Try with a v function and also wrap 01 in apostrophes: `%%=v(Lookup('LinkDE','link','linkid','01'))=%%`. Also, like mentioned before, make sure parameter names inside the function match DE column names.

Comment: Perfect, that worked!